# D-Link DIR-600M - Setting up QoS Rules to restrict bandwidth for given IP address

Tags: wireless-router, ip, bandwidth, qos

I'm trying to setup QoS rules to achieve the following:

I want to restrict the bandwidth for specific IP addresses that connect to the network. I'm confused about what goes in each of the fields seen in the screenshot seen below when setting up the QoS rules. Anyone who has done it before and can help understand what to put in each of these fields?

- Source IP
- Dest IP
- Source Netmask
- Dest Netmask
- Up Floor/Ceiling
- Down Floor/Ceiling

[image]

Comment: Me too... I don't know if it is wrong translated or if I don't know that dialect :)

Comment: I'd once got it to work somehow by trial-and-error but then unfortunately reset my router and lost all the effort... now want to do it the proper way after understanding. :-)

Comment: Almost everything I check online has a different interface or options with this feature... http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/mydlink-routers/dir-605l/how-do-i-configure-qos-quality-of-service-traffic-control-settings-on-my-router and for example...http://www.support.dlink.com/emulators/dir600/101NA/tools_firmw.html  Maybe try updating firmware and then looking over the options again....

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT also updated the firmware thinking would get a different interface but the interface remained same. And actually that is when i lost the settings that worked by trial and error earlier. I should've backed em up. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source IP : Where traffic from. If you set source IP with 192.168.0.1, traffics **from** 192.168.0.1 will be controlled.

Dest IP :  Where traffic heads to. If you set dest IP with 192.168.0.1, traffics **headed to** 192.168.0.1 will be controlled.

Source Netmask : Determines range of source IP address. It's according to IPv4 CIDR subnetting rule.

Dest Netmask :Determines range of dest IP address. It's according to IPv4 CIDR subnetting rule.

Up/Down Floor : Floor is **speed that you want to guarantee least**. For example, if you set Up/Down Floor to 10Mbps, you can guarantee at least 10Mbps speed for upload and download.

Up/Down Ceiling : Ceiling is **speed limit**. For example, if you set Up/Down Ceiling to 10Mbps, your upload and download speed is limited to 10Mbps, and you cannot use any more than that.

== Example ==
Source IP : 192.168.0.5
 Dest IP : 0.0.0.0
 Source Netmask : 255.255.255.255
 Dest Netmask : 0.0.0.0
 Up Floor/Ceiling : Floor 0 Mbps, Ceiling 10Mbps
 Down Floor/Ceiling : Floor 0 Mbps, Ceiling 10Mbps

Comment: that was implied. `can you explain with an example?` what would the values be in the first 4 fields if i would want to limit the bandwidth for ip `192.168.0.5` ??

Comment: Well, if you want to control traffic from 192.168.0.5 for maximum 10Mbps, it could be this :<br/><br/>Source IP : 192.168.0.5<br/>
Dest IP : 0.0.0.0<br/>
Source Netmask : 255.255.255.255<br/>
Dest Netmask : 0.0.0.0<br/>
Up Floor/Ceiling :  Floor 0 Mbps, Ceiling 10Mbps<br/>
Down Floor/Ceiling : Floor 0 Mbps, Ceiling 10Mbps,<br/><br/>This will limit traffic from 192.168.0.5 to 10Mbps max, and will not guarantee lowest speed. If you want to guarantee lowest speed, set Up/Down Floor with desired speed.

Comment: Sorry for messy comment. This thing looks like doesn't support line break.

Comment: can you update the answer with that info? easier to format there

Comment: and thanks for the input. I'll try it out today :) and let u know

Comment: I tried but did not understand the results :( E.g., if I have a 30Mbps link and add 192.168.0.100 with Celling 30000, I cannot add other IP!

Comment: I thought the sum of floor configs would be the maximum bandwidth, so when the other machines are turned off, the unique turned on could surf the 30Mbps. But dividing bandwidth with the Celling config is meaningless. So, all machines would use only 30Mbps/number of machines (if the same config is applied to all machines) and the bandwidth reserved to turned off machines is lost...